# ThisAddIn_ShutDown doesn't execute

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

In my add-in for Outlook, I have the following lines.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hazaa!");            
}

private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Shazoo...");
}
```

While Outlook greets me with a cool "Hazaa!" upon its start, it refuses to go "Sahzoo..." on me when I', closing it. Both methods are registered in the same way using the default, auto-generated code, so I don't suspect any errors there. The other explanation I can think of is that the shutting down process is executed when the application already has left the GUI and the shazooing is hidden.

Is it so? If not, how can I make Outlook shazoo me? If so, how can I notify a user visually of such a shazoo?

EDIT:

Apparently, since O10, the shut down is no longer to be called, so the auto-generated code below **is** indeed wrong (or at least not perfect). Courtesy of @Christian.K.

```
#region VSTO generated code
private void InternalStartup()
{
  this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
  this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using [Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee720183.aspx#OL2010AdditionalShutdownChanges_AddinShutdownChangesinOL2010Beta)?

> Starting in Outlook 2010, Outlook, by default, does not signal add-ins
>   that it is shutting down. Specifically, Outlook no longer calls the
>   OnBeginShutdown and OnDisconnection methods of the IDTExtensibility2
>   interface during fast shutdown. Similarly, an Outlook add-in written
>   with Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office no longer calls the
>   ThisAddin_Shutdown method when Outlook is shutting down.

Comment: Ah, MS ought to update auto-generated code, then. See the update in the original post. I sure **didn't** write that myself. Anyway, great info but it begs the question - how to I shazoo'fy my user upon the shut down?

Comment: I think they left in the machinery, although not executed any more, to not break existing code. Reading the article, I would say you shouldn't do that. Shutdown should be fast. Since the app (outlook) is exiting anyway, there is no point delaying that with a (modal!) user interaction.

Comment: I'm not arguing it's wise or preferable. But I'd like to know how to do so IF the client requests such a thing. Suppose they want me to write something to a DB or update CRM just as they exit the application. I won't be able to convince them about the advantages of a fast exit, then. But let me emphasize that I **agree** with your point.

Comment: Have you actually _read_ the article? See "Best Practices for Add-in Shutdown for Developers" for ways to still have code run at shutdown. Or "Best Practices for Add-in Shutdown for IT Administrators" for ways to (selectively) reenable the hooks.

Comment: Of course i did. Twice! And by that I mean "kind of"... Hrmp... And by **that** I mean "not at all". Shame on me... I saw the highlighted section of your answer and missed the link entirely... Please accept my apology.   :)

Comment: @Christian.K can you please help me clearing the same issue for powerpoint

Comment: @Christian.K  please help me in          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116448/how-to-enable-shutdownnotification-in-power-point-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Outlook 2010 you can ask Outlook to inform your plugin when it is shutting down.

```
[RequireShutdownNotification]=dword:0x1
```

The Key has to be placed in the Registry Folder of your Plugin

Comment: Are you referring to `AssemblyInfo.cs`?

Comment: No, this is a registry setting you need to make, see [the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee720183.aspx#OL2010AdditionalShutdownChanges_BestPracticesforAddinShutdownforITAdmin) I linked to in my answer under the topic "Best Practices for Add-in Shutdown for IT Administrators".