# File locked using FileStream for logging, is there anyway to trim while the file is opened?

Tags: c#, log4net, filestream, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm working with an Outlook plugin attempting to add logging to the code. I plan to next look into Log4net as everyone mentions this as a better option but for now I'm attempting to use the built in System.Diagnostics class for logging. Also I'm not sure if I can write to `%appdata%` with Log4Net or if I need to use a config file.

So here's my question, I've got a file that I'm writing to-

```
public static string logFilePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%") + @"\AppData\Roaming\OutLookPlugin\Application.log";
public static FileStream hlogFile = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

I'd like to be able to trim the file down so it does not get to large

```
public static void PerformFileTrim(string filename)
{
   var FileSize = Convert.ToDecimal((new System.IO.FileInfo(filename)).Length);

   if (FileSize > 250000)
   {
    var file = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();
    var AmountToCull = (int)(file.Count * 0.33);
    var trimmed = file.Skip(AmountToCull).ToList();
    File.WriteAllLines(filename, trimmed);
   }
}
```

I know if I close the file (ie - `hlogFile.Close();`) I can then trim my file but I don't want to close my file because my logging will stop.

Given that I'm working with an Outlook plugin the only thing I can think of is to experiment using the startup

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //trim file here
}
```

before logging begins to trim the file but I don't want to impact performance of the load time with disk IO.

Is there a way to write to the file without closing it?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. But it is involved, repositioning a stream that is linked to a Writer etc. Implementing log4net or any other log package would be quicker. As would your writing own rolling filename system.

Comment: I agree with Henk, just go with Log4net, will save you all the headaches you dont want.

Comment: OK, thanks for you're replies guys, I'll look at Log4Net. Can I point the log file to save to the user profile("%userprofile%") with Log4Net?

Answer (score -1):

I would not perform the filesize-test whilst running but only when Outlook is ending - then the logging Ends anyway.

Comment: I could attempt that but MS removed the build in shutdown code , that is it's still there by default but it's never called. This thread goes into detail about it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312619/thisaddin-shutdown-doesnt-execute) and there is an option in the link that I can attempt. Thanks for you're reply.